# What is the difference between name and displya name in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I found the following definition of a task in azure devops:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  name: 'CleanProjectsBeforeBuild'
  displayName: Clean Projects Before Build
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    projects: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
    custom: 'clean'
    arguments: '--configuration  $(BuildConfiguration)'
```

My question is ¿What is the difference between the 'name' property and the 'displayName' property?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find description here [Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#task):

> steps:
>
> -task: string  # reference to a task and version, e.g. "VSBuild@1"
>
> displayName: string  # friendly name displayed in the UI
>
> name: string  # identifier for this step (A-Z, a-z, 0-9, and underscore)